# How to write validations on below code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying form details in table format. But I want to apply validation for duplicate values.

I have two validations.

1. first time I will enter `min` value 1 and `max` value 100, now these values will display in table format on same page.
2. Now I will enter second time `min` value 101 and `max` value 200 or `infinity`, suppose I will enter min value between 1 to 100 it should not allow this because I already entered `max` value 100, so next it takes 101 too.

It is Possible in jquery or javascript?.

```
<table id="transaction" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Min</th>
         <th>Max</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
<form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
   <label>Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" />
   <label>Email:</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" />
   <label>Min:</label>
   <input type="text" name="min" id="min" class="stored" value="" />
   <label>Max:</label>
   <input type="text" name="max" id="max" class="stored" value="" />
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;" id="savebutton"><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i> Save </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try googling "validations in jquery" I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can check the values in javascript using onChange or onkeyup events for the textbox that you need to validate. You just need to compare the values with the values that you have stored earlier.